# Impossible to Add geometry attributes on a .shp file with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, fields-attributes

I am using QGIS version 3.8.3-Zanzibar
I have a shapefile and I want to compute the area by using Vector/Geometry tool/Add Geometry attributes.

Runnig this tool I get :

*Feature (11) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.06 seconds*

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Run the "Fix Geometries" processing algorithm against your data, and then try once again computing the area on the newly-generated temporary layer.

If it all looks good, save it out to a new shp or gpkg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please let me know where to find the "Fix Geometries"?

Comment: @Yan in the processing toolbox